# iCal and Mac Office 2011

Tags: macos, ical

I have a MacBook Pro user who uses Mac Office 2011 and he has been getting iCal invites from another user. When he gets them, he can't seem to respond to them (accept or decline).. the generated response seems to just sit in his outbox and never get sent.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: do you mean the user is using Outlook 2011 for mail and not Mail.app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is my experience that iCal and Outlook STILL do not play very nice together, although inviting from Outlook and accepting in Mail/iCal still seems to work much better than going the reverse direction.

There are some third party programs that tweak how ical sends invitations to make them more compatible

http://www.zamain.com/

But, yes this has been a known issue for years as any quick search for "ical outlook" will let you know! I thought this was supposed to be fixed once and for all with Office 2011, but I guess it has not been.

Comment: Yeah, it's too bad that they don't work well together...